# Can we create auto update/insert in a table from one database in different server on insert/update in a table from another database in another server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

I have two databases production one and pre-production, I want to map the changes I make in the production database to get inserted into the pre-production database. The problem is that both databases are on different servers. Is it possible to create a trigger or any other process to insert/update the same table in the pre-production database if that table gets updated in the production database?

I am trying to create a trigger but cannot find a way to do so. Also, I cannot use SSIS it is not available in our package.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do a [linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

This is not advised though as it could affect your production server's insert performance. Why not restore your pre-production db from your production's backup?